# Equivalent of CSS's numerical vertical-align in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In CSS, the `vertical-align` property can be used to vertically align an inline element's box inside its containing line box; see
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align. It can take various fixed values, such as `top`, `baseline`, `middle`, which seem to have Flutter equivalents, but it can also take a numerical length, such as `10px`, which I have not been able to find an equivalent of in Flutter. So, the question:

Is there a way to take a widget and vertically offset it by a specified number of logical pixels from its normal alignment according to baseline? (Say with `TextSpan`, or `WidgetSpan`, for a concrete example.)

I don't have access to the child element's height a priori, so using `Align` doesn't seem feasible, since that does the alignment with relative lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Involving your widget in a [Padding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) widget might work:

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: YourWidget(),
  )
```

You can specify only some sides of widget for into the Padding constructor with the `padding` property:

(See the [EdgeInsets Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets-class.html))

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10.0)
```

This way there will be a padding only at the bottom of the referenced widget.

Comment: That might work nicely! Do you know if padding has any side effects? For example, does padding prevent other boxes from overlapping the padded area?

Comment: It does prevent. You can see the padding as a blanket around your original widget. The resulting widget is still considered a widget sized as the combination of both.